# Get datepicker date on Kotlin TornadoFX

Tags: datepicker, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm studying the basics of TornadoFX for Kotlin.
I have this code:

```
class MainView : View() {
    override val root = vbox()

    init {
        with(root) {
            datepicker {
                value = LocalDate.now()
            }
            button("Choose date") {
                textFill = Color.GREEN
                action {
                    println("Button pressed!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when the button is pressed, I would like to take the date chosen by the user.

how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to have a `LocalDate` property bound to the `DatePicker`, like this:

```
class MainView : View() {

    private val dateProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>()

    override val root = vbox()

    init {
        with(root) {
            datepicker(dateProperty) {
                value = LocalDate.now()
            }
            button("Choose date") {
                textFill = Color.GREEN
                action {
                    val dateValue = dateProperty.value
                    println("Button pressed!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other solution would be to have the `DatePicker` instance in your class, and then take the value from it, like this:

```
class MainView : View() {

    private var datePicker : DatePicker by singleAssign()

    override val root = vbox()

    init {
        with(root) {
            datePicker = datepicker {
                value = LocalDate.now()
            }
            button("Choose date") {
                textFill = Color.GREEN
                action {
                    val dateValue = datePicker.value
                    println("Button pressed!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can implement a `ViewModel`, to separate UI and logic, see: [Editing Models and Validation](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part1/11.%20Editing%20Models%20and%20Validation.html)

Also, the style of your code can be improved: you can work directly with the VBox, like this:

```
class MainView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {

        datepicker {
            value = LocalDate.now()
        }

        button("Choose date") {
            textFill = Color.GREEN
            action {
                println("Button pressed!")
            }
        }
    }      
}
```